# How can I access to this value of this key in this JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to read the error message inside _body.

Currently, what I do is:

console.log(message._body.error);

However, I am getting undefined.

When I do console.log(message._body);

I get "{"code":141,"error":"This phone number exists already!"}"

```
var message = {  
"_body":"{"code":141,"error":"This phone number exists already!"}",
"status":400,
"ok":false,
"statusText":"Bad Request",
"type":2
};
```

By the way the following comes form the backend like this and I can't change its format neither remove the double quotes

```
   "_body":"{"code":141,"error":"This phone number exists already!"}"
```

How can I read the error message?

Comment: If this is a real `JSON` object, then you should `parse` it first (`JSON.parse(obj)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you need to convert it to json using the json() method after getting the error from your backend.

The following one should work fine with you:

> error.json().error

```
console.log(error.json().error)
```

Comment: You nailed it!! Thanks a looot!!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a property that contains a string of valid JSON.

You need to call `JSON.parse()` to convert that to an actual object.

Comment: It is not a string of valid JSON.

Comment: @gfrobenius: AFAICT, it is, but the OP isn't pasting it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your double quotes.  Do this...

`"_body":{"code":141,"error":"This phone number exists already!"},`

Here is a fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/cmht6u8f/1/

Comment: That's the thing, I don't have control on it as it comes from the back-end like that!

Comment: You'd have to show more code, the code for fetching it, and/or fix the back-end because you are showing invalid syntax.  It's not even a proper string.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to fix the json to it's proper form:

   ```
   var message = { 
       "_body":'{"code":141,"error":"This phone number exists already!"}',
       "status":400,
       "ok":false,
       "statusText":"Bad Request",
       "type":2
    };
   ```
2. parse the inner json and use it...

   ```
    var err = JSON.parse(message._body);
    console.log(err.error);
   ```